# How do I derive $1 + 4 + 9 + \cdots + n^2 = \frac{n (n + 1) (2n + 1)} 6$

Tags: calculus, summation, intuition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16)

I am introducing my daughter to calculus/integration by approximating the area under y = f(x*x) by calculating small rectangles below the curve.

This is very intuitive and I think she understands the concept however what I need now is an intuitive way to arrive at $\frac{n (n + 1) (2n + 1)} 6$ when I start from $1 + 4 + 9 + \cdots + n^2$.

In other words, just how came the first ancient mathematician up with this formula - what were the first steps leading to this equation? That is what I am interested in, not the actual proof (that would be the second step).

Comment: Induction is elementary too. How old is she?

Comment: she's 16 but math is not exactly easy for her. So I am looking for something intuitive.

Comment: This question was asked a multiple times, so have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60858/proof-by-induction-sum-limits-i-1ni2-fracnn12n16?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282349/summing-rr3-using-induction/282367#282367

Comment: I don't think this counts as a duplicate, since its asking for a proof which isn't by induction.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [Proof that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48080/752).

Comment: @AméricoTavares I agree - and there are many elementary non-inductive proofs there.

Comment: @nn4l You can also do it backwards, that is a very easy proof but extremely artificial: $\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}-\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}=k^2$. Then your sum becomes telescopic...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same as you can prove sum of n = n(n+1)/2 by

```
*oooo
**ooo
***oo
****o
```

you can prove $\frac{n (n + 1) (2n + 1)} 6$ by building a box out of 6 pyramids:

[image]
[image]
[image: enter preformatted text here]

Sorry the diagram is not great (someone can edit if they know how to make a nicer one). If you just build 6 pyramids you can easily make the n x n+1 x 2n+1 box out of it.

- make 6 pyramids (1 pyramid = $1 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + ...$ blocks)
- try to build a box out of them
- measure the lengths and count how many you used.. that gives you the formula

Using these (glued) [image]

Comment: this could be a fun activity to let children discover the formula by themselves.

Comment: someone knew this already http://math.stackexchange.com/a/48152/58512

Comment: this is very much what I was looking for. An intuitive way of understanding the series.

Answer (score 11):

Try using $(n+1)^3-n^3=3n^2+3n+1$. Take the sum of both sides.

Comment: More detail [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16/48094#48094).

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Use the fact that $(k+1)^3=k^3+3k^2+3k+1$

Comment: This isn't really an answer.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: sure, it's not. It's a HINT.

Comment: Yes - I was wondering why you would give a hint when it would be just as easy to give an answer!

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: giving a complete answer is often an easy thing, but giving help to OP and let him think such that he/she could understand the problem might be harder, but better for him/her.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice proof without words here : http://www.usamts.org/About/U_Gallery.php
Its a geometric proof of sorts which I guess could count as more intuitive than the somewhat contrived induction.

Comment: I must admit that I do not understand the geometric proof of _my_ problem at all. The other examples are brilliant though.

Comment: Basically you put 3 $n \times n$ squares onto a big rectangle. On the left you get a side of $2n+1$ while the top has length $1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2$. Thus $3 \cdot (1^2 + ... + n^2) = n(n+1)(2n+1)/2$, which gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

hint:let $a_n=1+2^2+...+(n)^2$ then $a_n-a_{n-1}=n^2-(n-1)^2$ then use recursive relation to prove $a_n= \frac{n (n + 1) (2n + 1)} {6}$  totally let $a_n=\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_ja_{n-j} +f(n) $ in your question $f(n)=An^k$ then compute $a_n^p$ and$a_n^g$ then $a_n=a_n^p+a_n^g$